# How to add the the attribute "required" based on radio selection in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form which changes it's required fields dynamically based on a part radio selection.

So a person chooses which way they want to be contacted in the radio:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="contactPref" id="SMS" value="SMS"/>SMS</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="contactPref" id="Twitter" value="Twitter" />Twitter</label>

<label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
<input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone"/>
<label for="twitterName">Twitter:</label>
<input type="text" name="twitterName" id="twitterName"/>
```

And depending on what they decide is their preferred mode of contact. After a field becomes selected, the corresponding text box should be made a required field. For example: if SMS radio field becomes selected then the Phone Number text box must be filled while the other fields becomes optional to fill. If a person chooses the Twitter radio, then the Twitter Name text box becomes a required field.

Here is my jsfiddle  [jsfiddle.net/lordro/q7Cxs](http://jsfiddle.net/lordro/q7Cxs)

My key issue is calling up the element and attribute as well as the syntax for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried with jquery? Why don't you put that html and your attempt in jquery into a jsfiddle so we can update it easily and you can learn more?

Comment: How are you validating your fields, what are you using???

Comment: This is my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/lordro/q7Cxs/

Comment: I added the alert as a check to see if the function even gets pulled up but it doesnt -.-

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[name="contactPref"]').on('change', function() {
    var isSMS = this.value=='SMS';
    $('#phone').prop('required', isSMS);
    $('#twitterName').prop('required', !isSMS);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TCjc/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery,

```
$("#SMS").change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#phone").attr("required", "required");
        $("#twitterName").removeAttr("required");

    }


});
$("#Twitter").change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#twitterName").attr("required", "required");
        $("#phone").removeAttr("required");

    }


});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PYByy/)

just note that

*

> "The required attribute of the  tag is not supported in
>   Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari."

*

Comment: Thats for your answer Arwa, since "required" is not supported on IE9 and Safari, do you have another idea with which to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I was thinking maybe something like an alert?